# passing serializable object from stackview widget gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-widget, android-pendingintent

AppWidget Provider (BroadcastReciever)

(Trying to send Serializable Object from Stackview Widget)
When i send int as extra though pendingIntent i am able to receive in the activity but when i try to send serializable extra it gives me null pointer exception
Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_profile_stackview);

// set intent for widget service that will create the views
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,WidgetProfieService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);


serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))); 


 remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter( R.id.widget_profilestackimageview, serviceIntent);


            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
            viewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            viewIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            viewIntent.setData(Uri.parse(viewIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, 0);
            remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_profilestackimageview, viewPendingIntent);

            // update widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

RemoteViewService(Sending extra int(image))

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {


   RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_profile);
rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.stack_profile_pic, ((Profile) mWidgetProfiles.get(position)).getImageId());
Log.d("profile",mWidgetProfiles.get(position).getCountry());

Log.d("profile",mWidgetProfiles.get(position).getImageId()+"");

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
```

> //
>   extras.putInt("profile",mWidgetProfiles.get(position).getImageId());
>   //using int extra works

```
  extras.putSerializable("profile",(Profile)mWidgetProfiles.get(position));
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.profile_widgetlayout, fillInIntent);



try {
    System.out.println("Loading view " + position);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rv;
```

}

Recieving Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
```

> /*
>        Using ExtraInt works here
>           ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_profilepic);
>
> ```
>     if(getIntent().getIntExtra("profile",0)!=0){
>         Log.d("widgetpic",getIntent().getIntExtra("profile",0)+"");
>         img.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("profile",0));
>     }
> ```
>
> */

```
ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_profilepic);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras !=null)
            if(extras.containsKey("profile"))
            {
            Profile mProfile= (Profile)extras.getSerializable("profile");
            img.setImageResource(mProfile.getImageId());
        }

    }
```

Comment: its still the same!!

Answer (score 0):

> passing serializable object from stackview widget gives null pointer
>   exception

Because sending `profile` key with bundle but trying to get `profile` from Intent which is returned by `getIntent()`. do it as:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras !=null)
      if(extras.containsKey("profile"))
        {
           Profile mProfile= (Profile)extras.getSerializable("profile"); 
        }
```

Comment: Hey ,Thanks for your response but i had tried that earlier too it still shows null and skips if as its not able to find "profile"